# Rules to be considered to be muslim

Tags: conversion

Salam,

With a simple answer, what to do to be muslim ? To believe that for sure there is God who is guiding the universe, to believe that he sent prophets is not enough ? To add to those things just Chahada ?

Comment: Your last question is certainly off-topic.

Comment: I've updated It, indeed you were right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As salaamu alaikum,

The Kalimah shahada holds the absolute requirement for one to be a Muslim - to profess and believe in Tauheed — that there is no god but Allāh, and he is the supreme and sole owner of all of his attributes, titles and entitlement of worship, and that the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) is his Messenger. But this single declaration is supported by very important details that Muslims must believe and act upon.

To only believe in one god who sent down prophets is not enough, we have to come to an understanding of **who** that one God is and what He has commanded from us in terms of belief and worship, and we have to come to an understanding of **who** these Prophets (AS) were and what was the substance of their messages, in particular what was revealed to the final messenger and prophet, Muhammad (SAW).

If one believes in a god who is the sole power, creator and authority for all of creation and believes that He has sent down prophets, but rejects anything that is stated in the Qur’an or from the tradition or Sunnah of the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) then they are not a Muslim.